# AVCaptureMovieFileOutput record audio only for the first video

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I'm developing an application using swift that record video for a precise duration. That's 7 sec in this example. 
All work's great for the first record, but the successive record doesn't contain audio but only video. 
I read something about changing the movieFragmentInterval of the AVCaptureMovieFileOutput instance, I try but nothing change.

```
 func setup(){
    self.session = AVCaptureSession()
    self.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

    // INPUT
    var devices : Array<AVCaptureDevice> = AVCaptureDevice.devices() as Array<AVCaptureDevice>
    var camera:AVCaptureDevice!
    var microphone:AVCaptureDevice!

    for device in devices{
        println("Device name: \(device)")
        if device.hasTorch && device.isTorchModeSupported(AVCaptureTorchMode.On){
            self.torch = device
        }
        if device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio){
            microphone = device
        }
        if device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo){
            if device.position == .Back{
                println("Device position: back.")
                camera = device
            }   }   }

    var error:NSErrorPointer = nil
    // audio
    if (microphone != nil){
        var audioInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: microphone, error: error)
        if error == nil{
            //  if !error{
            if self.session.canAddInput(audioInput){
                self.session.addInput(audioInput)
            }   }   }
    // video input
    if (camera != nil){
        var VideoInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera, error: error)
        //  if !error{
        if error == nil{
            if self.session.canAddInput(VideoInput){
                self.session.addInput(VideoInput)
            }   }   }


    self.output = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    var preferredTimeScale:Int32 = 30   
    var totalSeconds:Int64 = Int64(Int(7) * Int(preferredTimeScale)) // after 7 sec video recording stop automatically
    var maxDuration:CMTime = CMTimeMake(totalSeconds, preferredTimeScale) 
    self.output.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration

    self.output.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = 1024 * 1024 

    if session.canAddOutput(self.output){
        session.addOutput(self.output)
    }

    self.connection = self.output.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if self.connection.supportsVideoStabilization == true{
        println("video stabilization avaible")
        self.connection.enablesVideoStabilizationWhenAvailable = true
    }
    self.connection.videoOrientation = .LandscapeRight

    self.session.startRunning()
}

func startRecording(){
    self.output.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(self.tempPathURL, recordingDelegate: self)
}

func stopRecording(){
    self.output.stopRecording()
}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!){
    println("Finish recording")
    var success:Bool = false
    if error != 0 && error != nil{
        println("error")
        let value: AnyObject? = error.userInfo?[AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey]
        if value == nil{
            success = true
        }else{
            success = false
        }
    }
    if success == true{
        stopRecording()
    }
}
```

Comment: ever found the solution to this?

Comment: don't use maxRecordedDuration of AVCaptureMovieFileOutput to set the decided video duration. Stop the video recording using a timer.

Comment: thanks, that is what I was using before trying maxRecorded duration.  Problem with timer is that the output is not exactly the duration of the timer, and requires post processing to trim the extra recording.

Comment: I had similar problem, sorted it by removing output from session, creating new one and adding it back to the session. I also had to clean up tmp folder, it wouldn't overwrite existing file.

Comment: This example might help. You can see that he sets the max and preferred duration every time before starting recording.
https://ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/camera/record-video-with-avcapturesession-2